# Using the Progress Bar to tell me where it is in the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, progress-bar

I am currently writing a code that basically follows the algorithm (x3+1) in my original code. So the rule is, if the number is even, do (N*3)+1 else: N/2
But I am currently trying to add a progress bar to see how long it will take to solve up to the Nth number. (the algorithm would be in the for x in range loop)

```
import sys


def progress(count, total, status=''):
    bar_len = 60
    filled_len = int(round(bar_len * count / float(total)))

    percents = round(100.0 * count / float(total), 1)
    bar = '█' * filled_len + '-' * (bar_len - filled_len)

    sys.stdout.write('[%s] %s%s ...%s\r' % (bar, percents, '%', status))
    sys.stdout.flush()

import time 
total = 1001


for x in range(0,total):
    time.sleep(1)

    while x < total:
        progress(x, total, status='Doing very long job')
        x += x
```

When it prints out, you can see when its run that the progress bar is just on 0, how do I make it tell me which number is it at in the for loop?

Comment: Your `while x < total` loop will be infinite on `x = 0`. Change it to `x += 1`  and that may be what you desire.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I update the x variable to show the current for loop?

Comment: I've updated my comment

Comment: Actually this might work, thanks. I have Just tested it, and I figured out that its showing my the process its taking per loop, not which loop its up to, so haw can this be fixed?